# Range.Formula property not returning expected value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to get some information out of a formula in one of my excel sheets. The problem is, it isn't returning the value I expect it to be.

Here is my formula in the cell:

`="10000: " & INDEX('path\to\other\file\[file.xlsx]sheetName'!$B:$B, MATCH(10000, 'path\to\other\file\[file.xlsx]sheetName'!$A:$A, 0))`

The formula within the cell results in the expected value, but when I use `Range("A3").Formula` it returns the value of the cell, not the formula.

This only happens on one cell of a specific sheet. I loop through about ~120 sheets with about ~200 cells collectively and all other cells return expected results. All other cells have the same formula with a different number to match a different string. According to the [Range.Formula documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-formula-property-excel) this shouldn't be happening. What is going wrong?

**Edit 1:**

The two suggestions I've tried so far:

`.FormulaR1C1` returns the same result as `.Formula`

I couldn't find any differences between the cells that work and the one that doesn't so I copied a known functional cell and changed the number within the formula to get the information I wanted. This still gives the same results.

Comment: Don't have an answer, but have you tried Range("A3").FormulaR1C1?

Comment: Is there **anything** at all different about that cell? Like anything... may need to dig for differences ...

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I've been looking for the last 30 minutes. I've resorted to copying a cell that I know works (the one above it) and changing the 5 digit code to see if that helps. Unfortunately that didn't change the result.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers I get the same result from `.FormulaR1C1`